# Atualizando coleções com entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

É possível atualizar a `Collection` de uma entidade com relacionamento `one-to-many` através de sua `navigation property`?

```
public class Foo
{
  public virtual IList<Bar> Bars {get; set;}

  public int FooID { get; set; }
}


public void UpdateFoo(Foo foo)
{
  dbContext.Set<Foo>.Attach(foo);
  dbContext.Entry(foo).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

O comportamento do `EF` é adicionar os objetos de `foo.Bars` à tabela, sem remover os registros que não existem na coleção. A solução alternativa que encontrei foi realizar um `dbSet.RemoveRange` dos objetos não existentes em `foo.Bars` para excluí-los do banco de dados.

Qual é a maneira mais adequada para se atualizar uma collection?

EDIT-----------------

Analisando [este post de Daniel Simmons](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dsimmons/deleting-foreign-key-relationships-in-ef4), parece que a versão `6.x` do `entity framework` não suporta este recurso. O comportamento realizado pelo `ORM` é de modificar o valor das chaves estrangeiras para `null`, não deletando o registro.

Há alguma abordagem recomendada para realizar esta operação?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Até hoje não encontrei uma resposta que me explicasse isso adequadamente, então criei um algoritmo que uso para estes casos. Suponha uma entidade `Cliente` que tenha N `ClienteTelefone`s, e que isto faz parte de uma edição em um sistema ASP.NET MVC:

```
// Telefones Originais
var telefonesOriginais = db.ClienteTelefones.AsNoTracking().Where(ct => ct.ClienteId == cliente.ClienteId).ToList();

if (cliente.ClienteTelefones != null)
{
    // Telefones Excluídos
    foreach (var telefoneOriginal in telefonesOriginais)
    {
        if (!cliente.ClienteTelefones.Any(ct => ct.ClienteId == telefoneOriginal.ClienteId))
        {
            var telefoneExcluido = db.ClienteTelefones.Single(ct => ct.ClienteTelefoneId == telefoneOriginal.ClienteId);
            db.ClienteTelefones.Remove(telefoneExcluido);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }

    // Telefones Inseridos ou Alterados
    foreach (var telefone in cliente.ClienteTelefones)
    {
        if (!telefonesOriginais.Any(ct => ct.ClienteId == telefone.ClienteId))
        {
            // Telefone não existe ainda. Inserir.
            telefone.ClienteId = cliente.ClienteId;
            db.ClienteTelefones.Add(telefone);
        }
        else
        {
            // Telefone já existe. Marcar como alterado.
            db.Entry(telefone).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Aqui sempre dá essa exception quando marco como modified: Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of type '' have the same primary key value. Ensure that explicitly set primary key values are unique. Ensure that database-generated primary keys are configured correctly in the database and in the Entity Framework model. Use the Entity Designer for Database First/Model First configuration. Use the 'HasDatabaseGeneratedOption" fluent API or 'DatabaseGeneratedAttribute' for Code First configuration. Alguma ideia do que seja?

Comment: Consegui resolver. Era uma soma de coisas erradas. De qualquer forma sua resposta salvou minha pele, muito obrigado!